# make singleton object using xml in android

Tags: android

Is their any way to make singleton object by using xml.As we know if we write className with package it call the constructor of the class but i want to use this xml in various other xml files using include tag.But it call all the time its consturctor and creating various object of that.

```
  <jp.ne.biglobe.common.CustomSlidingDrawer>
  something
 </jp.ne.biglobe.common.CustomSlidingDrawer>
```

it call the constructor of the CustomSlidingDrawer class As i included it several other file.
Please Suggest me how to make it singleton object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a normal class, not singleton that you instanciate through xml. All instances would have a static method getView that returns the singleton.

But this would be awfull design. Just a syntactic workaround.

Regards,
Stéphane

Comment: Ya thnx for your response but i think it is just workaround and the problem is that is it possible to do so or not. Is their any tag or something in xml to do this task